# How to rename docker service in swarm?

Tags: docker, service, swarm

I have a docker swarm which runs a service named `web`.

For some reasons I want to rename it. I could delete the service and create a new one, but it's not quite good.

How to rename it to such as `old-web`?

Answer (score 0):

The command below used to work in older Docker versions:

```
docker service update --name old-web web
```

However, it is no longer supported and was removed in newer versions. See the following discussion for the more info: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25483.

Comment: I don't see this on their "service_update" documentation - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_update/

, Could you please point us to a direction or did you try it in your swarm mode?